# Update a value in a variable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a variable of double type called `_currentSliderValue` which I have given the value of *25 by default.*

As you can see in the video, I want to display the same time specified using the `Slider widget` when the user *changes the time value*. But it shows the default time of 25; Although I also used `setState` in necessary places.

Do you have an idea?

viedo:

[image]

The following codes are related to the `Slider` widget, which I use to change the numerical value of the `_currentSliderValue` variable. And because at the same time as that value is changed, the set state is also done, numerical changes can be seen But those changes are not saved and **by pressing the play button, the same initial fixed value is displayed.**

```
Slider(
            activeColor: green,
            value: _currentSliderValue,
            min: 25,
            max: 180,
            divisions: 31,
            onChanged: (valeu) {
              _currentSliderValue = valeu;

              state(() {});
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Did you initialize __currentSliderValue_  outside of build method ?

Comment: Why didn't you wrap your logic in onChanged in a setState block?

Comment: @belinda.g.freitas Yes that's right

Comment: @tomerpacific - Because it is not necessary. Just being by his side is enough. However, I entered the logic in settings mode, but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: Can you show what you do in button  onPressed method ?

Comment: @belinda.g.freitas Yes, Sure -  `onPressed: () {
setState(() {
isPlayed = !isPlayed;
});
if (isPlayed) {
setState(() {
_controller.start();
});
} else {
setState(() {
_controller.reset();
});
}
},`

Comment: @belinda.g.freitas Slider onChange codes  `onChanged: (valeu) {
              state(() {});
              setState(() {
                _currentSliderValue = valeu;
              });
            },`

Comment: I don't know how you wrote the code of the circle slider but I think the problem is from the way you're using the controller.